# How to validate a ASP.Net TextBox which should allow negative or positive decimal value with three decimal places?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I have a textbox which should allow user to enter only positive or negative decimal number with three decimal places. For Example: 73.345 or -2345.345 or -32.34. something like that. How to set the validation for this?

Whether validation is by either using Validation Controls or by JavaScript. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx) to do the work for you. Your regular expression, assuming the decimal point and digits immediately following are options, is then:

```
-?\d+(\.\d{1,3})?
```